# how to run my PHP script every 20 minutes

Tags: php, cron

I have one PHP script that I want to run every 20 minutes. I search in google and I see I must use CRON for that, I have to use FileZilla and putty to access my server. I found this:

https://crontab.guru/every-20-minutes
SO the code should looks like this:

```
*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path.php
```

I need to write in the putty?

Comment: Google `crontab -e`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Putty to connect to your server via SSH. It will give you a command line interface (CLI).

Once in the CLI, you need to type the following command:

> crontab -e

This will open the CRON config file. Then you need to add a line at the bottom of the file:

> */20 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path.php

Finally, you save and quit using `CTRL+X`

And that's it. The `PHP` script will be executed every 20 minutes. Of course, I'm assuming you're `SSH` access have the right permissions.

Now I don't know if your script `path.php` is already on your server, but this is where you need FileZilla, to upload the file on the server, or to update it every time you change it's content.